# Redundant tags: merge request

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I spotted two redundancies: "translation-de-to-en" and "translation-en-to-de" versus "german-to-english" and "english-to-german". Could a moderator please merge these tags? My preference would be to keep the latter two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with you. The tags are redundant. I also like the x-to-y version better.

I've merged the two pairs of tags.

Comment: That's great, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that "translation-de-to-en" and "translation-en-to-de" are gone? They still show up in my list of tags.